# Printing a number next to each String

Tags: java

I have a method that prints out the elements of a String array that are not null. Desired output:

```
1. cook
2. chef
3. baker
4. butcher
5. distiller
```

Output getting:

```
1. cook
3. chef
4. baker
7. butcher
9. distiller
```

The numbers aren't consecutive like they are in the first example. Obviously it's because it's only printing 'i' when 'i' is not null. Is there anyway I can make it look like the first example? I've tried different solutions but none of them seem to work.

```
public class Main {

public void testMethod() {
    String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null) 
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + myArray[i]);
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.testMethod();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep a counter:

```
public void testMethod() {
    String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null)  {
            System.out.println(++j + ". " + myArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use `i` as a counter, you'll need a separate counter :

```
public void testMethod() {
    String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null) 
            System.out.println((counter++) + ". " + myArray[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply keep a counter of how many you've printed, not just the indices:

```
public void testMethod() {
    String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
    for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != null) 
            System.out.println((++count) + ". " + myArray[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a new integer variable for counting.
Try this -

```
public class Main {
    public void testMethod() {
        int iter = 1;
        String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] != null) { 
                System.out.println((iter++) + ". " + myArray[i]);
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.testMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one more variable to `count` for `non-null values`

```
public void testMethod() {
        String myArray[] = new String[] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null,
                null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };
        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] != null){
                System.out.println((j + 1) + ". " + myArray[i]);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
1. cook
2. chef
3. baker
4. butcher
5. distiller
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
public class Main {

    public void testMethod() {
        String myArray[] = new String [] { "cook", null, "chef", "baker", null, null, "butcher", null, "distiller" };

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] != null) 
                System.out.println(((count++) + 1) + ". " + myArray[i]);
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.testMethod();
    }
}
```